# ¿Como puedo obtener el año y el mes actual?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Miren en este gráfico en mi proyecto con laravel, estoy tratando de plasmar la información que tengo en mi base de datos.

[image: Grafico de ordenes]

Lo que estoy graficando en realidad son las ordenes de producción de un taller según sus estados de producción.
tengo 3 estados para una orden de trabajo:
-EN PROCESO (color amarillo),
-NO TERMINADO (color rojo),
-TERMINADO (color verde)

Lo que se aprecia en el gráfico corresponden a las ordenes del mes de agosto y del mes de noviembre.
Me doy cuenta que estoy trayendo, todas las ordenes del año actual, incluido estos 2 meses.
**Solamente necesito traer las ordenes del mes y el del año actual**.

**¿Que le faltando a mi consulta para filtrar por el mes y el año actual?**

Esta es mi consulta en mi controlador:

```
public function getChartDoughnut(Request $request)
    {   
        $anio = date('Y');
        $estados = DB::table('orders as o')

        ->select(DB::raw('MONTH(o.date) as mes'),
                DB::raw('YEAR(o.date) as anio'),    
                DB::raw('(o.status) as estado'),             
                DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total'))        
        ->whereYear('o.date',$anio)
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(o.date)'),DB::raw('(o.status)'),DB::raw('YEAR(o.date)'))
        ->get();    

        return ['estados' => $estados, 'anio' => $anio];             
    }
```

Esta es mi tabla orders

[image: tabla orders]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas obtener el mes actual y pasarlo como criterio con la cláusula [`whereMonth`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses).

Por ejemplo:

```
public function getChartDoughnut(Request $request)
    {   
        $anio = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');
        $estados = DB::table('orders as o')
        ->select(DB::raw('MONTH(o.date) as mes'),
                DB::raw('YEAR(o.date) as anio'),    
                DB::raw('(o.status) as estado'),             
                DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total'))        
        ->whereYear('o.date',$anio)
        ->whereMonth('o.date',$month)
        ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTH(o.date)'),DB::raw('(o.status)'),DB::raw('YEAR(o.date)'))
        ->get();    

        return ['estados' => $estados, 'anio' => $anio];             
    }
```

Comment: tengo exactamente la misma consulta pero no grafica nada. Cual es el error?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz Haz un `var_dump` de lo que te devuelve `getChartDoughnut` y verifica si está obteniendo los datos que esperas o hay algún otro problema. El filtro hay que hacerlo de ese modo, pero puede que los datos no sean correctos, eso ya no depende de la consulta.

Comment: @ A. Cedano{
```"estados": [],
"anio": "2019"
}``` , ese es el resultado de lo que me trae la consulta

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz `estados` está retornando vacío. ¿Seguro que hay datos que cumplen el criterio en la BD?

Comment: @ A. Cedano  ```{
"estados": [
{
"mes": 12,
"anio": 2019,
"estado": "EN PROCESO",
"total": 1
},
{
"mes": 12,
"anio": 2019,
"estado": "TERMINADO",
"total": 1
},
{
"mes": 12,
"anio": 2019,
"estado": "NO TERMINADO",
"total": 1
}
],
"anio": "2019"
}```  si tenias razon no estaba retornado los datos que cumplan con la condicion

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Saludos.